# Running an initialization cell on Mathematica start up

Tags: options, initialization, cells

I am writing a bash script to run a bunch of Mathematica `.nb` files serially. So I thought I'd convert my Mathematica cells into `initialization cells`. However, I notice that the initialization cell isn't run on start up unless I evaluate it using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Is it not an initialization cell that I am looking for?

Steps I took to make my cell an initialization cell:

1. Selected the cell with mouse click
2. Cell > Cell properties > Initialization cell

### Edit

I just added `InitializationCellEvaluation -> True` as the first line of my file. However, how should I make this evaluatable?

Comment: Move your edits into an answer, so that others can use it, too.

Comment: @rcollyer I felt a little odd about answering my own question!

Comment: Its expressly encouraged. You might as well get the points for it.

Comment: @rcollyer Thanks mate! `:)`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think I found it but I'd be more than happy to look at other alternatives if any provided:

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to open **Options >
   Notebook options > Evaluation options > Global preferences** from the drop down menu at the top
2. Change `InitializationCellEvaluation` to `True` and `InitializationCellWarning` to `False`

The next time the .nb file is launched, the initialization cell is run.

Comment: Does it work to set it only for a specific notebook and leave preferences untouched?

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov It does but I changed it at the global level.