# Q-Function representation in Mathematica

Tags: function-construction, special-functions

I observed that there is no Q-function representation in Mathematica. The definition of Q-Function is:

\begin{align}
  Q(x) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_x^\infty e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}du \\
       &=\frac{1}{2} \mathrm{erfc}(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}})
\end{align}

a nother representation of  Q-function is:
\begin{align}
  Q(x) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{\left(\frac{-x^2}{2\sin^2{\phi}} \right)}d\phi
\end{align}

there is only Complementary Error Function representation Erfc.

$\mathrm{erfc}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{x}^{\infty} \exp(-t^2) dt$

Is there any possiblity that define a new function in *Mathematica*? so that it will be a permanent function.

Note:
In statistics, the Q-function is the tail probability of the standard normal distribution. In other words, Q(x) is the probability that a normal (Gaussian) random variable will obtain a value larger than x standard deviations above the mean.

Comment: How about: `q[x_] := Erfc[x/Sqrt[2]]/2;`

Comment: or even `q[x_] := SurvivalFunction[NormalDistribution[], x]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two parts to your question: how to define the function and how to make it persist between sessions. I suggested

```
q[x_] := Erfc[x/Sqrt[2]]/2;
```

though chuy's suggestion looks fine too.To make it persist, you can place this function definition in an initialization cell, and then this will run whenever the notebook is opened. You can find instructions for this [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7198/1783) and other information [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9484/1783) about running the cell on startup.

Comment: is it possible in the future versions in Mathematica contain this function? I mean can you tell them or suggest this to them?

Comment: I guess you might want to ask Wolfram about that. On the support page http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/ you can email them about bugs or with suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

If this the function that you use daily, you can put it into you initialization file. Use the command in a notebook:

```
$UserBasedDirectory
```

Usually there is a `./Kernel/init.m` file. It is evaluated when Mathematica kernel starts. You can put these line in it:

```
q::usage="q[x] is my Q-function. You cannot modify it, aha!"
q[x_:0] := Erfc[x/Sqrt[2]]/2
Protect[q]
```

Then you will have several good features:

[image: better def]