# Can we make "applets" with Mathematica?

Tags: programming

I've made a very simple photo resizer with Mathematica: It takes some files in a folder, processes them and write them into that folder. Now, I have to open the Mathematica file every time and evaluate the code. Is it possible to automate this? Perhaps making an applet or something? I tried to at least automate the closing of the code with `Exit[]` and `Quit[]` but it didn't work the way I wanted.

It would be really useful to have a file in my desktop and every time I open it, it automatically executes de resizing process and then closes. Notice that I don't need it to run in other computers that don't have Mathematica, I need it to run only on my computer that has Mathematica.

Comment: `Perhaps making an applet or something?` applets are dead. If you want to run the Mathematica code inside a browser, the CDF plugin is no longer supported. few years ago, one could have run a CDF inside a browser. Another option is to make a CDF file, and run it inside a Mathematica CDF player. But you will  not be able to avoid having to open something and click on a button to run it.    You could also try Mathematica online. There are many questions here about how to deploy Mathematica code online.  But I think the simplest thing is to make a CDF and use the player to run it using a button.

Comment: Also you could check the initialization code in notebook. These are cells which you can set to automatically execute/run when you open a notebook.  see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9484/running-an-initialization-cell-on-mathematica-start-up  You should be able to set the code in the initialization cell to automatically run the code you want and close the notebook at the end.  You could also make a mathematica script to do this all.

Comment: @Nasser The solution provided there doesn't seems to work.

Comment: You could create a Wolfram Language Script. These can be executed e.g. from a link or a command line.

Comment: @DanielHuber This worked perfectly! But when I run it, it does [this](https://i.imgur.com/SzWJyMt.png). Can we make it close automatically after the script finishes? Without having to press enter or esc?

Comment: @DanielHuber I switched from Conemu to the standard Windows terminal and it works the way I want. I guess the trouble in am finding has to do with Conemu, not with Mathematica.

Comment: E.g. if you put `"Hello">>"d:/tmp/test.txt"` in a script (**.wls), you can double click the file, the test file is written and the command windows is closed automatically.

Comment: @DanielHuber Yeah, I think this is a problem with Conemu.